# Prime-indexed primes and Sums of primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

## Background

My favorite example of [mathematical beauty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_beauty) is related to the early behavior of the primes. Consider two sequences:

### Prime-indexed primes

The first is defined by [A175247](https://oeis.org/A175247)$(n-1)$:

0. $2 = \operatorname{prime}(1)$
1. $3 = \operatorname{prime}(\operatorname{prime}(1))$
2. $5 = \operatorname{prime}(\operatorname{prime}(2))$
3. $11 = \operatorname{prime}(\operatorname{prime}(3))$
4. $17 = \operatorname{prime}(\operatorname{prime}(4))$
5. $31 = \operatorname{prime}(\operatorname{prime}(5))$
6. $41 = \operatorname{prime}(\operatorname{prime}(6))$
7. $59 = \operatorname{prime}(\operatorname{prime}(7))$

### Sums of primes

The second is defined by [A007504](https://oeis.org/A007504)$(n) + (1 + (-1)^n)/2$:

0. $0 = 0 + []$
1. $3 = 1 + [2]$
2. $5 = 0 + [2 + 3]$
3. $11 = 1 + [2 + 3 + 5]$
4. $17 = 0 + [2 + 3 + 5 + 7]$
5. $29 = 1 + [2 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 11]$
6. $41 = 0 + [2 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 11 + 13]$
7. $59 = 1 + [2 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 11 + 13 + 17]$

And incidentally matches the [lesser of twin primes](https://oeis.org/A001359) for the first few indices.

### Behavior

These sequences are similar for these 8 values but ultimately diverge asymptotically. The growth rates are $O(n\ln(n)^2)$ and $O(n^2\ln(n))$, respectively.

## Questions

1. Is there a link between these above differences at 0/2 and 29/31 and [regular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_number) (i.e. 5-smooth numbers)?
2. Are there any mathematical tools that could be used to try to allow 1 to be "half prime"?
3. Are there any concepts that would be able to explain what a prime at index $-∞$ might look like?

Comment: "half-prime" seems to be a strange concept (semiprimes are something completely different) and the idea of a prime at index $-\infty$ is also strange. Extremely many prime patterns can be detected holding for very small entries , but it seems no such pattern keeps holding if the numbers get larger.